# Azure RBAC and AKS not working as expected

Tags: azure-aks, azure-rbac

I have create an AKS Cluster with AKS-managed Azure Active Directory and Role-based access control (RBAC) Enabled.
If I try to connect with the Cluster by using one of the accounts which are included in the Admin Azure AD groups everything works as it should.
I am having some difficulties when i try to do this with a user which is not a member of Admin Azure AD groups. What I did is the following:

- created a new user
- assigned the roles Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster User Role and Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Reader to this user.
- Execute the following command: az aks get-credentials --resource-group RG1 --name aksttest

When I then execute the following command: kubectl get pods -n test I get the following error: Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "aksthree@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "test"

In the Cluster I haven't done any RoleBinding. According to the [docu from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/manage-azure-rbac#use-azure-rbac-for-kubernetes-authorization-with-kubectl), there is no additional task that should be done in the Cluster ( like for ex. Role definition and RoleBinding).

My expectation is that when a user has the above two roles assigned he should be able to have read rights in the Cluster. Am I doing something wrong?

Please let me know what you think,
Thanks in advance,
Mike

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use [AKS-managed Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/managed-aad), it enables authentication as AD user but authorization happens in `Kubernetes RBAC`
only, so, you have to [separately](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-ad-rbac) configure `Azure IAM` and `Kubernetes RBAC`. For example, it adds the `aks-cluster-admin-binding-aad` ClusterRoleBinding which provides access to accounts which are included in the Admin Azure AD groups.

The `Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Reader` role is applicable for [Azure RBAC for Kubernetes Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/manage-azure-rbac) which is [feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-identity#azure-rbac-for-kubernetes-authorization) on top of AKS-managed Azure Active Directory, where both authentication and authorization happen with AD and Azure RBAC. It uses [Webhook Token Authentication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#webhook-token-authentication) technique at API server to verify tokens.

You can enable Azure RBAC for Kubernetes Authorization on existing cluster which already has AAD integration:

```
az aks update -g <myResourceGroup> -n <myAKSCluster> --enable-azure-rbac
```

Comment: my bad, your answer was good but i miss clicked but cant change it until you edit something :(

Comment: @PhilipWelz: oh! edited to add some more clarification, there is always room for improvement!

Comment: thanks! i corrected it now :)

Comment: thank you for help. It works as it should now.

Comment: could you please mark the answers then as correct to help other users?