# Not able to read/write in the AKS Cluster even after assigning Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Writer role to the cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-rbac

I have a user named **rbacWriterAndConsoleNsReader** in my azure portal and assigned him **Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster User** role and Azure **Kubernetes Service RBAC Writer** role (scope= full cluster)

But when I try to list namespaces or even pods, it shows the below error :

```
Error from server (Forbidden): namespaces is forbidden: User "rbacWriterAndConsoleNsReader@mayankprac2outlook.onmicrosoft.com" cannot list resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope
```

PS: NO YAML files should be used (as role here is in-built role provided by Azure), All must be done through Azure CLI

Where am I going wrong ? Can anyone pls explain ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Hi Mayank, Could you share the error when you get the pods ?

Comment: Have you enabled  Azure RBAC for Kubernetes Authorization using `--enable-azure-rbac` ? See this for explanation - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69631070/azure-rbac-and-aks-not-working-as-expected

Comment: @YK1- Yes, I have enabled Azure RBAC for Kubernetes authorization using  `--enable-azure-rbac` , while creating the cluster. Morevover, enabled Azure AAD too using `--enable-aad`

Comment: @SureshVishnoi, Error when I get the pods is as : `Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "rbacWriterAndConsoleNsReader@mayankprac2outlook.onmicrosoft.com" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "abc1"` , where 'abc1' is the name of a namespace